# How to add a string inside an f-string while formatting it in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, formatting

I was padding an output in a print statement with a simple code which uses .format() function

```
print('{:-<100}'.format('xyz'))
```

I was able to get a similar output using f-strings by creating a new variable

```
library = 'xyz' 
print(f'{library:-<100}')
```

**Question:** Is there a way to add the string `'xyz'` inside the f-string without having to create a new variable?

I tried the code below, but it gave me an error:

```
print(f'xyz:-<100')
```

Comment: `print(f"{'xyz':-<100}")`

Comment: If you have *just* a single literal string, I would just use `print('xyz'.ljust(100, '-'))`. (It's actually faster than the corresponding f-string.) (Not that I'd care much either way, but it nips the "f-strings are faster" argument against it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, what you want to do is:

```py
print(f"{'xyz':-<100}")  # You can use expressions here, not only variables!
```

*PS: Regarding the error, are you sure you are running Python +3.6?*

Comment: The error is presumably a `NameError` for the undefined name `xyz`; the OP is already successfully using an f-string with a variable.

Comment: @chepner there are no `{}` surrounding the expression within the f-string, though, so there is no reason his code should throw an error. I ran it myself in both Python 3 and Python 2, and it only gave an error in 2.

Comment: I'm assuming a typo in the question, rather than a problem in the actual code.

Comment: thanks @Xiddoc the double quotes inside the single quotes / single quotes inside the double quotes does the trick for me. FYI : 'xyz' is a random string literal and not a variable. Apologies if the quesiton had a typo.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question right, then:

You can just use double-qouted string inside single-quoted f-string

```
print(f'{"xyz":-<100}')
```

and optional without f-string and format

```
print("xyz".ljust(100, "-"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to add the string ('xyz') inside the fstring without having to create a new variable.

Just add the string 'xyz' outside of the curly brackets '{}'

Example:
print(f'xyz{:-<100}')